# Find primes that satisfy conditions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

The problem is as follows: Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p-q$ and $pq-q$ are both perfect squares.

I found the solution $(3,2)$ by considering when $q$ is even. I then considered when both $p$ and $q$ are odd. The farthest I got was that $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, but I'm unsure how to continue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I could not prove that this is the only solution. But an approach is that $pq-q=(p-1)q$ is a perfect square if and only if $p=a^2q+1$ for some positive integer $a$. We then have $p-q=(a^2-1)q+1$ The case $a=1$ leads to your solution. $p=q$ is also impossible since $p^2-p$ is divisible by $p$ , but not by $p^2$.

Comment: Modulo $3$ we see that we must have $q\equiv 1\mod 3$ (unless $p$ or $q$ is divisible by $3$) , hence for $q=2$ , the only solution is $p=3$. Modulo $4$ , we can see that $p,q$ must be both of the form $4k+1$ , if they are odd. In particular, if $q>2$ , it must be of the form $12k+1$.

Comment: If another solution $(p,q)$ exists, we must have $p>10^9$

Answer (score 4):

For some integers $r \ge 0$ and $s \ge 1$,

$$p - q = r^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$pq - q = s^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, \eqref{eq2A} minus \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$pq - p = s^2 - r^2 \; \; \to \; \; p(q - 1) = (s - r)(s + r) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $p$ is prime, then $p \mid s - r$ or $p \mid s + r$. From \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}, we have $s \gt r \; \to \; s - r \gt 0$. Also, \eqref{eq1A} gives $q \le p$, so using \eqref{eq2A} note that $pq - q \lt p^2 \; \to \; s \lt p$. Thus, $0 \lt s - r \lt p \; \to \; p \nmid s - r$, which means $p \mid s + r$. Since $r \lt s \lt p$, then

$$s + r \lt 2p \; \; \to \; \; s + r = p \; \; \to \; \; s - r = p - 2r \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Substituting this into the RHS of \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p(q - 1) & = (p - 2r)(p) \\
q - 1 & = p - 2r \\
p - q & = 2r - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Next, substituting this into \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$2r - 1 = r^2 \; \to \; r^2 - 2r + 1 = 0 \; \to \; (r - 1)^2 = 0 \; \to \; r = 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

From \eqref{eq1A} with $r^2 = 1$, the only primes having a difference of $1$ are $p = 3$ and $q = 2$ (and using these values in \eqref{eq2A} gives $s = 2$).